# Allow users to run partial trust XBAP or BROSER WPF without touching internet explorer properties

Tags: vb.net, xaml, internet-explorer-9, xbap, partial-trust

I have just developed a xbap app which is hosted in an IIS server. Working fine in server and in the developers machines but when users access to it, the message "this application type has been disabled" appears. They only have to enable "XAML" for solving this error but I dont want them to do that.

I need a solution to allow users to run this app without changing anything in their explorer.

I cant believe Microsoft decided to not enable XAML apps to work directly since Internet Explorer 9!

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realized there's no solution directly in WPF Browser.

I am moving my app from that WPF Browser to asp.net web. Hard to simulate the same behaviour but moving forward so far...